# What's wrong with my algorithm?

Tags: c++, math

I was resolving some online mathematics tests, and thought it's too hard to find the solutions and put it in a program on devc++, I should have 
`153,370,371,407,`
but there was missing a `solution 407.`

Here is the question:  The number `153` has an interesting property. In other words, it is equal to the sum of the cubes of its digits:

```
 13 + 53 + 33 = 153
```

370 is another number with the same property. There are two other three-digit natural numbers with three different digits, both smaller than 500, that have the same property. Find them. 
And here is my program

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i,nr,a,b,c;
    for(i=100;i<=500;i++) {
        nr=i;
        c=i%10;
        b=i/10%10;
        a=i/10/10;
        if((pow(a,3)+pow(b,3)+pow(c,3))==nr) cout<<nr<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Read your question to yourself for a second and try to phrase it so a total stranger could understand

Comment: Try to use if (abs(pow(a, 3) + pow(b,3) + pow(c, 3) - nr) <= eps) ... where eps is a smalest float or double value.

Comment: are you sure your answers are correct?  If we consider 153, then we evaluate `1^3 + 5^3 +3^3` which is `1 + 125 + 9` which is 135.  I though that dyslexia may have slipped in, so a quick check of 370 would have us evaluate `3^3 + 7^3 +0^3` which is `9 + 343 + 0` or 352.

Comment: @thurizas Reconsider your `3^3 = 9`. Twice.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `pow`s return `double` leading to floating point inaccuracy.

Instead, try

```
if(a*a*a + b*b*b + c*c*c == nr)
    cout ....
```

Answer (score 1):

( [EDIT] Resolved since. <s>Mostly guessing the question from the partial code, since the question is terribly formatted at this point, and is not editable either for some reason.</s> )

Floating point calculations are not always exact, and comparing floating point values for equality is generally ill advised.

To the point, replace

```
if((pow(a,3)+pow(b,3)+pow(c,3))==nr)
```

with

```
if((a*a*a + b*b*b + c*c*c) == nr)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run that program I get those 4 answers.

`pow` is never **supposed** to be imprecise enough to have any rounding in this trivial test.

But there seems to be a tend in questions on SO that both pull c headers into C++ and use `system("pause");` that a version of `pow` is being used that is seriously less accurate than it ought to be.  So the earlier two answers (suggesting a way to not use `pow`) may be effectively correct.  But only because something is wrong with you math library, not because a valid copy of `pow` gets that bad.

So you could find a better C++ environment or better math headers, or you could start some seriously defensive programming around the flaws in your copy of `pow`

But if that doesn't fix it, the next thing to suspect would be `endl` isn't working quite correctly before that `pause`.  Maybe you are seeing some output buffering problem.  Anyway, I'm pretty sure the code is fine (even its use of `pow`) and the problem is in the math or I/O library functions.

Comment: `pow is never *supposed* to be imprecise enough to have any rounding in this trivial test` Would you have a reference for that? `pow` is a floating point function returning a floating point value. I am not aware of any particular accuracy guarantee that would cover the case in question here.